# Is it a problem to use SQL server Express for small MVC project?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc-2

So I know most of the limitations to SQL Server express (2008 R2) such as DB size limit, CPU, SQL server agent...etc.

I am working on a personal small Ecommerce ASP.NET MVC project that won't hit the DB size limit, and I don't think I would be hitting the CPU limit based on the amount of traffic the (current NON-MVC) site see's now.

I originally started this project with using MySQL, but I am more comfortable with SQL than MySQL so I was thinking on move to it.

However, I don't know if the lack of SQL server agent in the Express edition would be huge enough that I should consider staying with MySQL or not.  The site is going to be hosted who has database backup abilities themselves.

1) Should I stick with MySQL?

2) Is there a way around the inability to start/use the SQL Server agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What job(s) would you want SQL Server Agent to perform? For example, if you were only looking for backup, but the host already has backup capabilities, what else would you need to work around?

As to whether you should switch, it might become a personal decision. You may be more comfortable with SQL Server, but sticking with MySQL on a relatively small project helps you gain some new experience. You'd also have to weigh the expected productivity gain of working in a familiar territory against the upfront effort / time it would take you to make the switch.

Comment: Not to mention the potential licensing costs of a full-blown SQL Server implementation.